# How to get the data from parent site to sub site using Lookup Column?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

please suggest me the best way to get the data from parent site to sub site using Lookup.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is create a site column at the top level site (IT) which is a lookup to your vendors list, then in your sub site you add the site column into your custom list.

Please refer steps mentioned article.

[Creating a cross site lookup field without code](http://bramnuyts.be/2011/04/11/creating-a-cross-site-lookup-field-without-code/)

Answer (score 1):

The best way that I know of is to create the lookup column on the parent site as a site column. Go to this url (Assuming youre working on SP2013):

```
_layouts/15/start.aspx#/_layouts/15/mngfield.aspx
```

Once the lookup is created you can choose it on both the parent site and on the subsite.